# Executing a command from Objective C

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, command-line

I want to execute a command from objective C (Cocoa framework). The command I am trying is as below. I tried with NSTask but it says "launch path not accessible" when I execute it.

```
sudo ifconfig en0 down
```

My code is:

```
- (void)testme {
NSTask *task;
task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[task setLaunchPath: @"sudo ifconfig en0 down"];

NSArray *arguments;
arguments = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"foo", @"bar.txt", nil];
[task setArguments: arguments];

NSPipe *pipe;
pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
[task setStandardOutput: pipe];

NSFileHandle *file;
file = [pipe fileHandleForReading];

[task launch];

NSData *data;
data = [file readDataToEndOfFile];

NSString *string;
string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog (@"command returned:\n%@", string);

[string release];
[task release];
```

}

Answer (score 5):

`sudo ifconfig en0 down` is not a sensible launch path. The correct launch path for this command would be `/usr/sbin/sudo`.

Once that is done, you still need to pass the correct arguments to `setArguments:`. `foo` and `bar.txt` look like example code that you copied without reading.

**MORE IMPORTANTLY, THOUGH, running `sudo` from NSTask will not work.** You will need to use [Authorization Services](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/security/Reference/authorization_ref/Reference/reference.html) to launch a privileged command.

Comment: Ok. I could run it via "    char *command = "sudo ifconfig en0 down";
    system(command);" but it asks me system admin credentials. Any idea how to get rid of it?

Comment: You can't. Use Authorization Services.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the full executable path and you should specify the arguments as the arguments, not along with the launch path. `NSTask` ain't a shell, it internally uses syscalls (`execv()`, I guess) to invoke the command.

```
NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[task setLaunchPath:@"/usr/bin/sudo"];

NSArray *arguments = @[@"ifconfig", @"en0", @"down"];
[task setArguments:arguments];
```